# How can I take a photo of a detected rectangle in Apple Vision framework

Tags: ios, computer-vision, rectangles, apple-vision

How can I take a photo (get an CIImage) from the successful VNRectangleObservation object?

I have a video capture session running and in `func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)` I do the handling, namely

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                   didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                   from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }

    do {
        try handler.perform([request], on: pixelBuffer)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Should I save somewhere the pixel-buffer that I pass to the handler and manipulate on that buffer? It's a damn shame that I can not access the image as a property from the observation object :(

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) this is not a question _that_ broad to close it 2) you should specify the context in which you use VNRectangleObservation. As I understand, you use it on image (not video). Don't you have the original image by the time completion closure called?

Comment: If you didn't understood  someone (not me) voted to close your question as too broad, while I was trying to prevent this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So you're using a Vision request that produces `VNRectangleObservation`s, and you want to pull out the regions of the subject image identified by those observations? Maybe perspective-project them, too, so that they're rectangular in the image plane? (There's a demo of this [in the Vision session from WWDC17](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017-506/?time=1500).)

You can extract and rectify the region with the [`CIPerspectiveCorrection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveCorrection) filter from Core Image. To set that up, you'll need to pass the points from the image observation, converted to pixel coordinates. That looks something like this:

```
func extractPerspectiveRect(_ observation: VNRectangleObservation, from buffer: CVImageBuffer) -> CIImage {
    // get the pixel buffer into Core Image
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: buffer)

    // convert corners from normalized image coordinates to pixel coordinates
    let topLeft = observation.topLeft.scaled(to: ciImage.extent.size)
    let topRight = observation.topRight.scaled(to: ciImage.extent.size)
    let bottomLeft = observation.bottomLeft.scaled(to: ciImage.extent.size)
    let bottomRight = observation.bottomRight.scaled(to: ciImage.extent.size)

    // pass those to the filter to extract/rectify the image
    return ciImage.applyingFilter("CIPerspectiveCorrection", parameters: [
        "inputTopLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: topLeft),
        "inputTopRight": CIVector(cgPoint: topRight),
        "inputBottomLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomLeft),
        "inputBottomRight": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomRight),
    ])
}
```

> Aside: The `scaled` function above is a convenience extension on `CGPoint` to make coordinate math a bit smaller at the call site:
>
> ```
> extension CGPoint {
>    func scaled(to size: CGSize) -> CGPoint {
>        return CGPoint(x: self.x * size.width,
>                       y: self.y * size.height)
>    }
> }
> ```

Now, that gets you a [`CIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext) object — those aren't really displayable images themselves, just instructions for how to process and display an image, something that can be done in many different possible ways. Many ways to display an image involve [`CIContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624114-init) — you can have it render out into another pixel buffer, or maybe a Metal texture if you're trying to do this processing in real-time — but not all. On the other hand, if you're just displaying static images less frequently, you can [create a UIImage directly from the CIImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624114-init) and display it in a `UIImageView`, and UIKit will manage the underlying `CIContext` and rendering process.

Comment: Please advise here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399074/cidetector-not-detecting-proper-rectangle-in-ios

Comment: How to enlarge perspective captured image let say by 5-10%? or is there are way to expand (in perspective) the rectangleObservation points?