# CIDetector not detecting proper Rectangle in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, object-detection, cidetector

I am trying to detect a `Rectangle` using `CIDetector`.

I am using code from this: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/vnimagescanner

My problem is when I am trying to detect any `Rectangle` object, sometimes it's detecting or sometimes it's detecting `Odd Rectangle` (please see below images). I tried to search this Google but didn't find any solution of this.

> Normal case:

[image]

[image]

> Some bad case:

[image]

Here is my code to set the `CIDetector Accuracy` :

```
func highAccuracyRectangleDetector() -> CIDetector? {
   var detector: CIDetector? = nil
   detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorAspectRatio: 1.43, CIDetectorMaxFeatureCount: 5])

   return detector
}
```

If you will look into third image, it's highlighting without `Rectangle` object.

Is it possible to detect or to display the highlighted green overlay when there will be a proper `Rectangle`? Please suggest me.

Comment: Someone has worked on this?

Comment: Might help to use the Vision framework and `VNDetectRectanglesRequest` instead. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage) for that part of Core Image say Vision is better if you’re on iOS 11 or later.

Comment: I tried using Vision framework but its blinking too much and detecting with odd case also.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the an Open source library `WeScan` by WeTransfer to detect Rectangle/Document scanning and this give accurate result. I followed below link:

> https://github.com/WeTransfer/WeScan